# In Python how do you insert the answer of raw_input into the middle of a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def number_of_legs():
    print " The sparrow has how many legs"
    legs = raw_input()
    print "You said the sparrow has ",+ legs"legs" 


number_of_legs()
```

Comment: When you run this you get:
    `print "You said the sparrow has ",+ legs"legs" 
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Take the time to read the console output most of the times the solution is there. In your case you obviously have a syntax error at line 4

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a plus for concatenation:

```
print "You said the sparrow has " + legs + " legs"
```

Give string formatting a try instead:

```
print "You said the sparrow has {0} legs".format(legs)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

```
print " The sparrow has how many legs"
legs = raw_input()
print "You said the sparrow has {} legs".format(legs)
```

Will output: (if legs is 15)

```
You said the sparrow has 15 legs
```

Also, I should suggest that you can place a string as an argument to [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input). Like so:

```
legs = raw_input("The sparrow has how many legs? ")
print "You said the sparrow has {} legs".format(legs)
```

When I run this:

```
The sparrow has how many legs? 25        # 25 is my input and that's it
You said the sparrow has 25 legs
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def number_of_legs():
    print " The sparrow has how many legs"
    legs = raw_input()
    print "You said the sparrow has, "+legs+"legs"
number_of_legs()
```

Try this. Just need to get your quotes, plus sign and comma in order.

Answer (score 1):

Use str.format

```
print "You said the sparrow has {0} legs".format(legs)
```